# .htaccess authentication for directory internal server error

Tags: .htaccess

Trying to password protect a directory on my website by using the .htaccess file but I am getting an internal server error after entering my username and password. The directory is located at example.com/admin/

this is the .htaccess file in the admin directory of my site.

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Please enter your username and password"
AuthUserFile /###/admin/.htpasswd
Require user myusername
```

and the .htpasswd file is in the same directory as the .htaccess file, I have tried changing the `AuthUserFile` path to just .htpasswd, also tried admin/.htpasswd, but keep coming up with an internal server error

my .htpasswd file looks like this:

```
myusername:#passwordencrypted#
```

I am on godaddy hosting if that could be the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AuthUserFile /home/###/###/###/html/###/admin/.htpasswd` It turns out the actual directory for admin was much more complex then I could have known and I found a useful piece of php which found the path to the .htpasswd file for me at http://www.htaccesstools.com/articles/full-path-to-file-using-php/.

```
<?php
    $dir = dirname(__FILE__);
    echo "<p>Full path to a .htpasswd file in this dir: " . $dir . "/.htpasswd" . "</p>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

For those SSH & Terminal lovers, you can also log in via SSH and type in **pwd** to find the full directory to the file.  It stands for "print working directory" and will print the directory path to the file all the way from the root.